# Adding dimension with specified value: Is it currently possible?

Tags: dimensions

Measureit extension does great in adding dimensions to models. 
But sometimes, as the model becomes complex, it is difficult to design at right dimensions/proportions, so that dimensions are shown correct.

Is there a way to specify the dimension value manually?

Comment: So what is your question about - avoiding incorrectly shown dimensions ? Or do you want to have a way to select any piece of geometry and enter its dimensions from keyboard ? If the second that's not possible unless separating it and changing dimensions from the Object mode.

Comment: Thanks. It's the second one. It would be nice if _measureit_ extension allows manual entry of dimensions.